# QRCode generated with special characters can not be read in html input

Tags: html, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I generated a qrcode with text `530µ 590`, and then I use the PDA `unitech ea600` to scan, if I open a page with chrome in the PDA, the html input only show `530 590`, the special char `µ` missed.

But if I use the scan app in the PDA or use the url address bar, the whole text `530µ 590` will be shown there.

Comment: Can you show us the QR code you created? And the programming code you used? Thanks :-)

Comment: @TerenceEden I found the root cause, its the PDA bug, the supplier has provided a new version PDA, it works fine.